# Setting default issue type in JIRA

Tags: jira

I have a Kanban board in the cloud-based version of JIRA that uses the JIRA Software Simplified Workflow.  When I create a new issue, it automatically assigns a "Backlog" status.  I would like the default status to be "Selected for Development" instead.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I exhausted all the Google leads I could find.

Comment: Why would you WANT to do that? If every issue you create is selected for development, would that not violate Kanban's WIP limit?

Answer (score 1):

The status is nothing to with the Kanban board - it comes from the assigned workflow for that project, which is why you choose a project and a type first when creating a new issue - that then determines which workflow you're going down.

If *Backlog* is your first workflow status, then the issue will go there first. If you need it to go to *SFD* on creation, then you need a new workflow where that is the first stop.

But as Sarov says, if everything goes into *SFD*, then surely the selection process is being ignored?

Answer (score 1):

- The **default issue type** is the type of the issue that is selected when you Create a new issue (bug/task/etc). You can set this via Administration > Issues > Issue type schemes
- The **default status** an issue starts in (todo/done/etc) is set in the workflow (Administration > Issues > Workflow), add a transition from the start (create issue) to the desired status
- The **default column** on the kanban board is configured in the board settings. You can choose between a kanban board with or without a backlog. In the board settings define the mapping between a status and a place on the board.